# How to resize image and keep scalable

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design

When I size all jpg's to the same size the layout works fine. But when they are different sizes they don't fit nicely into the divs I have. I've added a code snippet that shows the problem.  The last two pictures are vertically just a little bit too big

Here's my HTML and CSS

```css
#firstSection {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
}
.otherSections {
  width: 25%;
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}
img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 479px) {
  #firstSection,
  .otherSections {
    clear: both;
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<main>
  <section id='firstSection' >
      <img  alt="DSC_001.jpg" src="http://www.sailwbob.com/skipper/public/img/DSC_001.JPG"/>
  </section>
  <section class='otherSections'>
      <img alt="DSC_002.jpg" src="http://www.sailwbob.com/skipper/public/img/DSC_004.jpg"/>
      <img alt="DSC_003.jpg" src="http://www.sailwbob.com/skipper/public/img/DSC_005.jpg"/>
  </section>
  <section class='otherSections'>
            <img alt="DSC_002.jpg" src="http://www.sailwbob.com/skipper/public/img/DSC_004a.JPG"/>
            <img alt="DSC_003.jpg" src="http://www.sailwbob.com/skipper/public/img/DSC_005b.jpg"/>
  </section>
   </main>
```

Comment: can you add some fake image to your example so your piece of code is usefull to see your issue . you can link use images from http://dummyimage.com or any other site of the same kind

Comment: I like http://placehold.it/; but yeah, it's hard to visualize without actual amages in place.

Comment: I changed the images src and saw the result. There was a large image beside 4 small images. What is the problem?

Comment: Do you want the image to stay fixed in relation to the container - in which case they can skew, or be cropped (using background-image property); or do you want the image container to change? It's unclear what you want.

Comment: @FarzinKanzi From the question: "But when [the images] are different sizes they don't fit nicely"

Comment: As i see they fit nicely. What you want exactly?

Comment: I've included a live snippet that shows the problem, the last two jpgs don't fit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all your images have the same width/height ratio (, or at least approximately the same, like 3:2 in all your example images) you could do it with background images and some javascript:

1.) Create empty DIVs, set their widths to 50% or 25%

2.) Apply background images to all of them, using `background-size: cover`and `background-repeat: no-repeat`

3.) Since the DIVs won't have a height (background images don't count as content), you have to define their heights: Get the width of the parent element (window?) using javascript

4.) Calculate the height according to the width percentage and the image ratio and set that as height via javascript. For a 25% wide DIV that height would be `parentwidth * 0.25 * 2/3`, for the 50% wide DIV `parentwidth * 0.5 * 2/3`

ADDITION:

Here's a codepen where I did all that: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Bpmxxd

And here's the same in a snippet:

```js
parentwidth = $('main').innerWidth();

height1 = parentwidth * 0.5 * 2/3;
  $('#firstSection').height(height1);

height2 = parentwidth * 0.25 * 2/3;
  $('.otherSections').height(height2);
```

```css
main {
  border: 1px solid red;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#firstSection {
  background: url(http://www.sailwbob.com/skipper/public/img/DSC_001.JPG) no-repeat center;
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
}
.x1 {
    background: url(http://www.sailwbob.com/skipper/public/img/DSC_002.JPG) no-repeat center;
}
.x2 {
   background: url(http://www.sailwbob.com/skipper/public/img/DSC_003.JPG) no-repeat center;
}
.x3 {
   background: url(http://www.sailwbob.com/skipper/public/img/DSC_004a.JPG) no-repeat center;
}
.x4 {
   background: url(http://www.sailwbob.com/skipper/public/img/DSC_001.JPG) no-repeat center;
}
.x1, .x2, .x3, .x4 {
  width: 25%;
  float: left;
}

#firstSection, .otherSections  {
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<main>
  <section id='firstSection'>
  </section>
  <section class='otherSections x1'>
  </section>
  <section class='otherSections x2'>
  </section>
  <section class='otherSections x3'>
  </section>
  <section class='otherSections x4'>
  </section>

</main>
```

Comment: the first 3 images all have the size 600px X 400px and the layout works fine for those 3 jpgs.  It's only when we try to add the last 2 jpg that have much different sizes.

Comment: the size isn't the problem - it's the ratio between width and height. If the images still are in landscape format, it should work - `background-size: cover` makes sure the DIV is filled It maybe cuts off a little bit, but the DIV size is kept that way.

Comment: I thought this would work but the images don't scale properly

Comment: you have to reload the page after you set it up - the javascript only goes into action on page load.

Comment: I added jquery and used document.ready() along with (window).resize() and it works perfectly.  Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

you could use [object-fit](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit):

```css
#firstSection {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.otherSections {
  width: 25%;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}
img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;
  object-fit: cover;
  border: solid;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  object-position: right top;
}
img + img {
  object-position: center center;
  }
#firstSection img {
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 479px) {
  main,
  #firstSection,
  .otherSections {
    clear: both;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    height: auto;
  }
}
main {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  height: 100vh;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://bfred-it.github.io/object-fit-images/dist/ofi.min.js"></script>
<main>
  <section id='firstSection'>
    <img alt="DSC_001.jpg" src="http://www.sailwbob.com/skipper/public/img/DSC_001.JPG" />
  </section>
  <section class='otherSections'>
    <img alt="DSC_002.jpg" src="http://www.sailwbob.com/skipper/public/img/DSC_004.jpg" />
    <img alt="DSC_003.jpg" src="http://www.sailwbob.com/skipper/public/img/DSC_005.jpg" />
  </section>
  <section class='otherSections'>
    <img alt="DSC_003.jpg" src="http://www.sailwbob.com/skipper/public/img/DSC_005b.jpg" />
    <img alt="DSC_002.jpg" src="http://www.sailwbob.com/skipper/public/img/DSC_004a.JPG" />
  </section>
</main>
```

Comment: ["Internet Explorer: No support"](http://caniuse.com/#search=object-fit).  This kills the good idea.

Comment: @JosephMarikle You can take a look at   https://github.com/bfred-it/object-fit-images demo http://bfred-it.github.io/object-fit-images/demo/

Comment: Here is an old fiddle I put together that does exactly what you need.

https://jsfiddle.net/gemlarin/vz9c03yt/

Comment: @GCyrillus.  Object fit sort of works but then the images don't resize nicely when the size of the browser window is changed

Comment: @DCR  Maybe you would consider https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-position to choose how image should be clipped ,  i  also added the polyfill for IE in the snippet with object-position

Comment: when you use object-fit the images don't scale in a nice way

Comment: @DCR , the idea is to keep the **initial ratio** and **crop the image itelf** if needed . What do you mean by *not in a nice way* ? pixellisation, should be ratio be modified , should the crop sides be different ? else ? The idea is also to keep image in the document. :) maybe you could show us a few screenshot of what you expect to see when it is resized.